# More than one package matched with specified pattern. Please restrain the search pattern

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, publish-profiles

My pipeline was working fine when I used Azure Resource manager Connection Type. Now I lost access of AD and the client secret for Service principle expired. Hence I planned to switch the pipeline connection type to Publish Profile. But since than I am getting above error. Yes, I have multiple Zip file, but I am pointing to the one which is needed. I don't want to create separate build pipelines for Dev and Prod. Below is the Pipeline set up:

[image]

and this is the error  I get:

[image]